# apply model coefficients on new data

Tags: r

I have two matrices `sub` and `macro_data`. They include the estimated coefficients of a model and the macro data, respectively

```
> sub
        coeff      varname
1   -1.50          gdp      
2    0.005         inflation     
3   -2.4           constant  

> macro_data
    gdp        inflation 
1   18.0      -0.17  
2   15.8      -0.14 
3   17.7      -0.15
```

I would like to apply the following formula: -1.5*gdp+0.005*inflation-2.4 in order to get the scores.

I have tried

```
for (i in 1:1){
  sub$coeff[i]*macro_data[,1]+sub$coeff[i+1]*macro_data[,sub$coeff[i+1]]+sub$coeff[i+2]
}
```

Actually it works but this is not the best solution, because I would like something general. Any idea?

Comment: Why loop over a single number of `i`? Also `i+3` will be out of bounds? You might want: `sub$coef[1] * macro_data$gdp + sub$coef[2] * macro_data$inflation + sub$coef[3]`.

Comment: correct, it was i+2, but i am lost in my own loop i dont know how to apply the formula above

Comment: `cbind(macro_data, 1) %*% sub[, "coeff", drop=FALSE]` Normally the function `predict.~()` can take a parameter `newdata=`

Comment: @jogo thanks a lot, does it make sure that the colnames match?

Comment: @branchwarren http://mathinsight.org/matrix_vector_multiplication

Comment: @jogo thanks for the link but my question was not very clear. what happened if in the matrix `sub` you have a different order (i.e. constant and then inflation and then gdp) when you do the matrix multiplication you would have mistakes if i am correct no?

Comment: @branchwarren In this case you have to reorder or the columns of `macro_data` or the elements of the coefficient vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136828/discussion-between-jogo-and-branchwarren).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a matrix multiplication:

```
cbind(macro_data, 1) %*% sub[, "coeff", drop=FALSE]
```

If your coefficients are from estimating a model, then normally the function `predict.~()` can take a parameter `newdata=` to claculate estimates for new data.

For your example data this wont work because you have dataframes. This will do:

```
sub <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"coeff      varname
 -1.50          gdp      
  0.005         inflation     
 -2.4           constant ")

macro_data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"gdp        inflation 
1   18.0      -0.17  
2   15.8      -0.14 
3   17.7      -0.15")

m <- cbind(macro_data, constant=1)
C <- sub$coeff
names(C) <- sub$varname
m$gdp*C["gdp"] + m$inflation*C["inflation"] + m$constant*C["constant"]
```

The last line can be shorten to:

```
as.matrix(m) %*% C[names(m)]
```